# Backbone router creates multiple views which causes multiple events to bind to the same view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm new to backbone.js and trying to understand how routes, views etc works and now I have a problem with events building up for the same view. here is a clip that will show you exactly what I mean. http://screencast.com/t/QIGNpeT2OUWu

This is how my backbone router looks like

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "pages": "pages",
    }
    pages: function () {
        var page_view = new PageView();
    }
});
```

So when I click the Pages link I create a new PageView and this is the code I'm using

```
PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#content"),
    initialize: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/pages',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        });
    },
    events: {
        "click td input[type=checkbox]": "updatePublishedStatus"
    },
    updatePublishedStatus: function (event) {
        console.log('update publish status');
    }
});
```

pretty basic I guess but as you can see in the clip each time I navigate to /pages I get another event registered to the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things going wrong here.

1. Your video indicates pages being a collection well, `Pages`. `Pages` being a `Backbone.Model` with attributes such as Page name, slug, published etc... You lack that and it's going to hurt. You shouldn't just load some html and push it to your DOM, this defies the whole purpose of using Backbone in the first place.
2. If you do create a Model for a Page it will have a View. Then your /pages route will show the view of the Collection Pages etc.
3. You will fetch your data not inside a view's initialize but rather by doing `pages.fetch();` where pages is an instance of the `Pages` collection. This can happen before you even initialize your router.
4. When changing attributes through your view, the individual models will be updated.

As a sidepoint: Fetching data on initialize is not great. You can call render() before you actually get the data and that's no fun.
Also instead of doing `$('#content')` you can use the view's $el. As in `this.$el.html(...);`

Comment: Ok, I understand that Models and Collections should be used. I use asp.net mvc and when /pages is called I just return a partial view with all the html and data because I haven't figure out how to make it work with or without javascript enabled if I don't use a partial view. Do you have any experience of creating a rich web application with asp.net mvc which also is unobstrusive and works without javascript enabled?

Comment: No man sorry I don't, I love my python ;) But if your aim is to make an app which does not depend on having javascript, and ignores the idea of having models behind your Backbone views, you should probably reconsider using Backbone in the first place.

Comment: Alright I see :) ... I think I'll come up with a solution and I agree with you that I should use models and collections.

Comment: Is it so bad to render before data is fetched? If the view renders empty, then re-renders or updates when the 'reset' event is fired, it is not so bad.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke no that's minor, but at least it needs a bind to reset.

Answer (score 1):

Move `var page_view = new PageView()` to be outside of `Router.pages()`.

Have the `PageView.initialize()` success callback save `data` to a variable. Either in `PageView` or in a model.

Add a `render` function to `PageView` that sets `$("#content").html(data);`.

Call `page_view.render()` within `Router.pages()`.

Comment: In that case, render can be called before the data has been fetched.