# Rich web app using ASP.NET MVC and Backbone.js and progressive enhancement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, backbone.js

I'm working on a small web app using mvc and backbone.js and I have a couple of thoughts about how to handle async request vs regular requests.

Today I use a controller called /pages which returns a partial view if it's a ajax request and a standard view if it's a regular request. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367957/backbone-router-creates-multiple-views-which-causes-multiple-events-to-bind-to-t) I was told I'm doing it all wrong when I send a bunch of HTML back to the client.

So how should I structure my controllers etc to handle both async and non async requests?

In my case I have the following code in my pages controller

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var id = _model.Id;
    var parentId = _model.Parent != null ? _model.Parent.Id : null;
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel
    {
        RootModel = _session.Query<IPageModel>().SingleOrDefault(model => model.Parent == null),
        CurrentModel = _model,
        ParentModel = parentId != null ? _session.Load<IPageModel>(parentId) : null,
        Children = _session.Query<IPageModel>()
            .Where(model => model.Parent.Id == id)
            .Where(model => !model.Metadata.IsDeleted)
            .OrderBy(model => model.Metadata.SortOrder)
            .ToList()
    };

    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        return PartialView(viewModel);    
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

But if I understand things correctly I would be better off sending back a collection of pages instead of a complete view model? How should I handle this in my controller?

Is it a good idea to create a separate controller/api using eg. the api controller in mvc 4?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Backbone then you should return JSON insted of the `PartialView` and the `PartialView` should be a template in the page where the Backbone view will render that.

Comment: Ok, in my case, should I just return a collection of IPageModels or is it ok the send back the complete view model? I guess sending back a collection is the way to go?

Comment: It depend if your view template is neads these data from viewmodel yes else i will go with collection

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier in different answers you should return JSON result instead of HTML view.[JSON Result on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx)   [Example of using JSON result](http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/)

If you are using [ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) (as of now beta) you can use [web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) to get data in JSON through ajax/rest call.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Florim. You should be returning json from your MVC controllers. Backbone was built with REST in mind. Therefore your server should mimic a REST API, and return json for Backbone to work with. When I work with MVC 3 and Backbone, all my server code does is return the data. It usually has one view and that is the Backbone Application View. The web app "views" are rendered using templates from the data that is returned from my controllers. Hope this helps.

I have not played with the MVC 4 Web API as of yet, but I do think this situation would be the ideal choice for it.

Comment: Ok, what's your take on progressive enhancement with backbone.js and MVC? This is a blog post about the subject  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

Comment: Is it possible to use razor views as templates or I'm I better off using e.g jquery templates or underscore?

Comment: I use underscore's templates and pass the json returned from the server into the templates. Exactly how they do on the demo todo.js. If you dont want to build your own REST API on the server, you can consider using https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/ - built by the masters here. I have not used it before, but definitely considering using it in future applications. There is a backbone example in the link i provided. It uses Redis for data-access, but I am pretty sure you can use Entity or anything you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled a couple of Backbone examples together into a working ASP.net MVC 3 application that is using REST interface. Here is the link to my [tumblr Blog](http://www.tumblr.com/blog/kalpers) where I have provided information to the source code and the websites I used as resources. Backbone.js works really well with MVC 3 and I am always looking for new ways to push this example.